# Import declaration

Tags: java

I'm reading the Java 8 specification to better understand the Java language.

Specifically, the **Chapter 7 Packages**.

However in **7.5.2 7.5.2 Type-Import-on-Demand Declarations** I don't understand 
the case where we can use `TypeName` according to the following syntax:

```
import PackageOrTypeName . * ;
```

The specification says:

> If the PackageOrTypeName denotes a type (§6.5.4), then the name must
>   be qualified (§6.5.5.2), or a compile-time error occurs.

So I jump to **6.5.4** but the following is very unclear:

> If the PackageOrTypeName, Q, occurs in the scope of a type named Q,
>   then the PackageOrTypeName is reclassified as a TypeName. Otherwise,
>   the PackageOrTypeName is reclassified as a PackageName. The meaning of
>   the PackageOrTypeName is the meaning of the reclassified name.

So I can't imagine how to use `TypeName`.

Please, can anyone provide me with an example to import types with `*` with
`TypeName`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be forgetting about nested classes. An example would be:

```
import java.util.Map.*;
```

Which would import `Entry`. It can now be used like this (unqualified):

```
Entry<String, String> e = ...;
```

Another way to do this import is:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Where `java.util.Map` is the name of a type.

Comment: Another example would be import of static functions from some class

Comment: @RC I thought about that, but that would have the form `import static PackageOrTypeName.*;`.